# How to calculate the determinant $\det(A+xI)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ symmetry matrix with the diagonal elements of $A$ are $0$ (the diagonal elements of $A$ are can also be any constant ). Let $I$ be an  $n\times n$ identity matrix, and Let $x$ be a constant. How to calculate $\det (A+xI)$? We wish $\det (A+xI)$ be express by the combinations of $\det(A)$.

Comment: Do you mean: by combination of [*minors*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_%28linear_algebra%29) of $A$?

Comment: "the diagonal elements of $A$ are $0$ (the diagonal elements of $A$ are can also be any constant )" what do you mean? Are the other elements of $A$ variables?

Comment: @Surb It means $A$ is a real symmetry matrix  which its diagonal elements  are $0$  or its diagonal elements are the same real constant $a \neq 0$ . How to  calculate $det (A+xI)$, with  $x$ is a real number ? And we wish $det (A+xI)$ can be expressed by the combinations of $det A$.

Comment: @ccorn No,it is  the combination of $det A$, and it also means $det (A+xI)$ is expressed by the polynomial of $det A$.

Comment: I do not understand what you are looking for.

Comment: @ccorn  Can $det (A+xI)$  be written to  the  polynomial of   $det A$?

Answer (score 4):

If $A$ is diagonalizable:

$$A=U^{-1}DU$$

And
$$\det(A)=\prod \lambda_i$$
Where $\lambda_i$ is the eigenvalues

Thus
$$\det(A+xI)=\det\big(U^{-1}(D+xI)U\big)=\det(D+xI)=\prod (\lambda_i+x)$$

Comment: Note that for $n=2$, $det(A+xI)=det(A)+x*tr(A)+x^2$

Answer (score 1):

That's impossible (unless $n=1$), as the determinant of $A+xI$ depends on the eigenvalues of $A$ rather than the determinant of $A$. Consider, e.g. $A_1=\pmatrix{1\\ &4}$ and $A_2=2I_2$. They have the same determinants, but $\det(A_1+xI)=(x+1)(x+4)\ne(x+2)^2=\det(A_2+xI)$.

Answer (score 0):

for $n=3$, $$\det(A+xI)=x^3-tr(A)x^2+(A_11+A_22+A_33)x+\det A$$